deploying from Matlab to ARM breaks because of '\'
I run Matlab under Windows. I am new to this so hopefully this is dead simple problem. I try to deploy a model to arm-based device by pressing [Build Deploy Start] And I get this message:

Backslash '\' detected in block diagram name. Forward-slashes '/' should be used as the separator before block names.

Seems like it should be simple setting like set the path delimiter or so, but I could not figure out.
Here is stack trace:
 Error using codertarget.utils.invokeDownloader
 The following error occurred during deployment to your hardware board:
 Backslash '\' detected in block diagram name. Forward-slashes '/' should be used as the separator before block names.
 
 Error in codertarget.tools.BuildHook/after_make
 
 Error in coder.coverage.BuildHook.dispatch_after_make (line 347)
                 after_make(hookH);
 
 Error in coder.internal.ModelBuilder>i_buildProcedure (line 1599)
 if ~isempty(lBuildHookHandles)
 
 Error in coder.internal.ModelBuilder.make_rtw (line 119)
                 [buildResult, mainObjFolder] = i_buildProcedure...
 
 Error in build_target
 
 Error in build_target
 
 Error in build_standalone_rtw_target
 
 Error in slbuild_private
 
 Error in slbuild_private
 
 Error in sl_feval
 
 Error in slbuild
 
 Error in slbuild
 
 Error in slprivate
 
 Error in coder.internal.toolstrip.HardwareBoardHandler/standaloneBuild (line 121)
             cbinfo.domain.buildModel(this.ModelHandle);
 
 Error in codertarget.sltoolstrip.EmbeddedHardwareBoardContext/standaloneBuild (line 252)
             this.HardwareBoardHandler.standaloneBuild(cbinfo);
 
 Error in codertarget.sltoolstrip.EmbeddedHardwareBoardContext/buildDeployStartHardwareBoardActionCBInternal (line 218)
             this.standaloneBuild(cbinfo, this.getSelectedBuildActionTS('Start'));
 
 Error in coder.internal.toolstrip.HardwareBoardContext.buildDeployStartHardwareBoardActionCB (line 346)
                 context.buildDeployStartHardwareBoardActionCBInternal( cbinfo ); - Show complete stack trace'


Did you use any backward slashes in your model? That's what the error message is saying after all. It's rather hard for us to debug your code if you don't show us your code.

no as far as I now. I tried to go over text files and change everything to / but I might be doing something wrong. Actually I am trying to use model from github. https://github.com/darenlee/SimulinkARDroneTarget

have you tried command fullfile to build paths? fullfile will use either '/' or '' depending upon the operating system you are using, possibly avoiding the above error message.

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html
